# Ionic The setup task has been deprecated

Tags: ionic-framework

Fllow http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html
When I use $ ionic setup sass, I got:**The setup task has been deprecated**.
How can I customising Ionic with Sass? I use Ionic 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open index.html in www/ of your ionic app.
The instructions are on the 11th line...
What you have to do is;
1) run 'gulp sass' in the terminal whilst in your ionic app directory
2) then uncomment link to href="css/ionic.app.css" in your index.html file
3) comment out or delete link to href="css/style.css"
NB: the ionic.app.scss file can be found in the scss folder in the root directory of your ionic app. Happy coding!!!

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But everytime I edit ionic.app.scss, I have to run 'gulp sass'.